# Is there a way to keep POSTed XML in tact in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

I have a REST API in my Rails app that users will be posting XML to. I know that Rails (perhaps Rack in this case) converts the posted data to a params hash.

I'm curious if there's a way to get Rails to not convert the XML to a params hash? Instead, I'd like to get the XML as a string. I'd rather not have Rails convert to a hash, and then use `to_xml` to convert it back to an xml string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I needed to do in the controller action to get the raw xml from the POST request:

```
request.raw_post
```

The [raw_post](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/raw_post) method for a request will return the raw body of the request.

Answer (score 2):

The XML data should be sent as a parameter in the POST request. In your unit tests it would look something like this:

```
xml = <<-XML
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <hash>
      <foo type="integer">1</foo>
      <bar type="integer">2</bar>
    </hash>
XML
post :my_api_path, { 'model_data': xml }
```

In your controller you would extract the `model_data` parameter (and parse it as XML if you wanted to extract data from it):

```
class XmlPassingController
  def save
    # XML as a string
    pp params[:model_data]
    # XML used for attributes to create a model instance
    my_model = MyModel.from_xml(params[:model_data])
    pp my_model
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm hoping to avoid needing to create a model for this, but it seems unavoidable since I don't like the "<hash>" node that Ruby throws in.

Comment: @mstrom you could always create a custom method that sets attributes according to how you want them set: `my_model.some_field = my_xml['different_fields'][23]`

Comment: Ok, figured out what I needed. I posted an answer below. Thanks for your help.